# How much database column length should i allocate for Google Maps place_id?

Tags: google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API and need to store relations of my own geo objects to administrative areas using reverse geocoding in SQL database. I want to use `place_id` to uniquely identify area, but docs don't give me a clue about how long it may be. Should i use `varchar(255)` as usual?

Comment: I can't find any reference regarding the length of the `place_id` too... (but it is always 27 characters long through) **BUT, if you are using it as key, keep in mind that a `place_id` does not have a 1 to 1 relationship with a place. (one place can have multiple `place_id`s)

Comment: @kaho, yes, it's not very good, but i'm ignoring possibility of multiple `place_id`'s for now. I've just seen reports that previous API version have used quite long IDs, so i'm little bit afraid to restrict length; on the other side, i'm not happy to use too lengthy field as well.